# Laravel Query builder - OrWhere + Where

Tags: laravel

I have the following query:

```
public function getPvpBattle()
    {
        $battle = PvpBattle::where('player1_id','=',$this->id)
        ->orWhere('player2_id', '=', $this->id)
        ->where('mode','!=','FINISH')
        ->first();
        if ($battle) return $battle;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

For some reasons, it doesn't work as excepted on every user, and it returns different rows for `player1_id` and `player2_id` which supposed to be in the same battle.

What's wrong in this query and how I can make it to work and reutrn the same result for `player1_id` and `player2_id` which belongs to the same row?

Comment: You can check the SQL result using `toSql` method. Check if it's the SQL you are expected.

Comment: it shows me `select * from `pvp_battles``, Although I have 2 where's and 1 OrWhere

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using this query?

```
$id = $this->id;

$battle = PvpBattle::where('mode', '!=', 'FINISH')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('player1_id', '=' , $id)
            ->orWhere('player2_id', '=', $id);
    })
    ->first();
```

Read more about advance query [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses).